# Installing Prometheus on GKE + istio

Tags: prometheus, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I'm trying to install Prometheus on istio running on GKE by following [This doc](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing#adding_prometheus)
. It looks like the link provided there for fetching `install-prometheus.yaml` file is broken. Any idea where I can get it?

`curl https://storage.googleapis.com/gke-release/istio/release/1.0.6-gke.1/patches/install-prometheus.yaml | kubectl apply -n istio-system -f -`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud offers version `1.0.6-gke.3` manifest, so this workaround is no longer required.

---

I experienced the same error with GKE 1.12.6-gke.7 / Istio 1.0.6-gke.1 cluster. I tried applying the old version of prometheus manifest file into the cluster; prometheus metrics collecting functions are seems working fine.

```
$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/gke-release/istio/release/1.0.3-gke.3/patches/install-prometheus.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: This works fine too. Thanks. Did you manage to set up a gateway so that you can access prometheus externally?ie. From a browser?)

Comment: While this works, I would be very careful installing version-specific configuration on top of GKE Istio add-on. Google is probably going to address this soon.

Comment: @nkigen I set up an Istio gateway and a virtual service for `prometheus.istio-system.svc.cluster.local` in default namespace and can see prometheus console via a browser.