# How to install helm chart prometheus-operator on GKE with prometheusOperator.admissionWebhooks.enabled=false?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I want to install the `helm` chart `stable/prometheus-operator` on a GKE cluster. I'm aware that either firewall rules need to be adjusted or hooks need to be disabled by setting `prometheusOperator.admissionWebhooks.enabled=false` (for details see the [README](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator#running-on-private-gke-clusters) of the chart).

However, if I install the chart with

```
    - wget -qq https://get.helm.sh/helm-v3.0.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz && tar xf helm-v3.0.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz && mv linux-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin
    - helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
    - helm repo update
    - kubectl create ns monitoring
    - kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/master/example/prometheus-operator-crd/alertmanager.crd.yaml
    - kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/master/example/prometheus-operator-crd/prometheus.crd.yaml
    - kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/master/example/prometheus-operator-crd/prometheusrule.crd.yaml
    - kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/master/example/prometheus-operator-crd/servicemonitor.crd.yaml
    - kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/master/example/prometheus-operator-crd/podmonitor.crd.yaml
    - helm install monitoring stable/prometheus-operator --namespace=monitoring --wait --timeout 10m --set prometheusOperator.admissionWebhooks.enabled=false
```

in GitLab CI the pod `prometheus-operator` has two containers which remain in state "Pending" for 5 minutes. I expect this rather simple setup to be available within one minute.

You can inspect the cluster setup at https://gitlab.com/krichter/prometheus-operator-503/-/jobs/358887366.

The approach shown in [Installing Prometheus on GKE + istio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55475552/installing-prometheus-on-gke-istio) doesn't apply because I didn't install istio.

Comment: When you have pods in `Pending` state use `kubectl describe pod $pod_name` to see (at the bottom of output) events from from this pod. They may show the issue which prevents pods from being scheduled properly in GKE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a known issue in the helm chart. According to https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/19147 the issue can be avoided by setting `prometheusOperator.tlsProxy.enabled=false`.